# Using powerbuilder 12.5 to call web service method returns null response

Tags: .net, web-services, null, powerbuilder

Any suggestions/solutions/tips will be much appreciated.

I'm using PowerBuilder 12.5 to call a .Net Web Service and the call works and is received by the WS who send a valid XML response but the response object when loaded by PB is null.

The proxy project is using .Net option to generate PB proxies. Some WS methods work fine and response object is accessible in PB code but when calling some of the other WS methods the PB object assigned to hold the WS method's response is null even though the response XML is correct and contains the expected values (captured using fiddler). On visual examination the proxies generated by PB appear to match the WSDL definition.

I need to be able to check the WS method call's response in the code so the application can take appropriate action if it fails.

The WSDL is:
    http://cbre.truelogic.com.au/service.asmx?WSDL

Example PB code:

Same WS, 1st method call to `GroupInsert()` works but although the 2nd method call to `ContactBulkImportWithGroups()` works, PB fails to interpret the method response and load the response object (even though response XML is correct).

```
// Web Service = lws_cl, already created earlier in script.

// Get Group ID - This WS method call works
wspn_campaignlogic_group ln_ret_group
decimal ldc_groupID[1]

ln_ret_group = lws_cl.GroupInsert(ls_groupName)
if isValid(ln_ret_group.GroupResults) then
    if ln_ret_group.GroupResults.ResultCode = 1 then
        ldc_groupID[1] = ln_ret_group.GroupID
    end if
end if

// Contacts - This WS method returns null
wspn_campaignlogic_contactbulkimporter ln_ret_contact   
any la_xml

ln_ret_contact = create wspn_campaignlogic_contactbulkimporter

la_xml = '<contacts><c><f>Jill</f><l>Jackson</l><e>jj@yahoo.com</e><comp>Acme Solutions</comp><sal></sal><p>(02) 8080 1111</p><m></m></c></contacts>'
ln_ret_contact = lws_cl.ContactBulkImportWithGroups(3, ldc_groupID, la_xml, "dd/mm/yyyy")

// Check results
if NOT isValid(ln_ret_contact) then
    // Error - execution goes in here because ln_ret_contact is null so result cannot be checked by code
else
    // OK
end if
```

XML Response: captured by Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 06 Jul 2012 04:39:42 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-UA-Compatible: IE=8
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 688

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><ContactBulkImportWithGroupsResponse xmlns="http://new.cl.truelogic.com.au/"><ContactBulkImportWithGroupsResult><ImportResults><InvalidContacts><contacts xmlns=""></contacts></InvalidContacts><Updated>1</Updated><Inserted>0</Inserted></ImportResults><ContactImportResults><ResultCode>1</ResultCode><ResultDescription>Success.</ResultDescription></ContactImportResults></ContactBulkImportWithGroupsResult></ContactBulkImportWithGroupsResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to CREATE the instance of the structure that gets returned by the service call.  All you need to do is declare it - and it gets populated as the return value from the method call.

Take that CREATE statement out.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks but it makes no difference. I tried the code with and without the create response object statement before each of the two WS method calls. The GroupInsert() still populated the response but the BulkImport() returned null regardless of whether or not I used the create response object statement.